# How to set multiple properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable an element and also set its placeholder in Javascript.

I'm able to do this with the below code (I'm referring to the `writecontent` element).

```js
function toggleType() {
    var type = document.querySelector('select[name="type"]').value;

    if(type == 'Review') {
        aboutreview.style.visibility = ('visible');
        document.querySelector('.writecontent').disabled = true;
        document.querySelector('.writecontent').placeholder = "Not available in Review";

    } else if (type == 'Discussion' || '') {
        aboutreview.style.visibility = ('hidden');
        document.querySelector('.writecontent').disabled = false;
```

Instead of calling the element twice, how would I set the `disabled` and `placeholder` at the same time when calling the element the first time?

Comment: Btw your second condition won't do what you think. You need `if (type == 'Discussion' || type == '')` or `if ((type || 'Discussion') == 'Discussion')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be by storing the element reference in a variable.

```
 const writeElem  = document.querySelector('.writecontent');
 if (writeElem) {
     writeElem.disabled = true;
     writeElem.placeholder = "Not available in Review";
 }
```